# How do I add a list in listView where the list has been populated?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I wonder how to add a new item to a listView where the listView already has populated by data ?

In **Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**, there has a add `button`, `listView` (value get from SQLite).

When the add button is clicked, it will go to **Edit_Staff** and finally return the value to **Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**.

Image below shows **Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**. As you can see it has one list, which was retrieved from SQLite.

[image]

**Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**

```
public class Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView extends Fragment {

    PicCustomBaseAdapter obj;
    ArrayList<ImageAndText> images=new ArrayList<ImageAndText>();
    ListView listViewEdit;
    StaffAPI sqlcon;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    public static final int PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View edit_details = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_staff_list, container, false);
        listViewEdit = (ListView)edit_details. findViewById(R.id.listViewEditStaff);
        add=(Button)edit_details.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        sqlcon = new StaffAPI(getActivity());
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            ID = bundle.getLong("ID");
            BuildEditStaffList(ID);
        }

      add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickedPosition = -1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Staff.class);
                //Log.e("ST","S");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
          return edit_details;
    }

    public void BuildEditStaffList(long id) // retrieve data from SQLite 
    {

        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor cursor1=sqlcon.readName(id);

        String[] columns=new String[]{
                MyDatabaseHelper.Image,MyDatabaseHelper.Claim_Type,MyDatabaseHelper.Amount,MyDatabaseHelper.Description};

        int[] to=new int[]
                {
                        R.id.image, R.id.type,R.id.amount,R.id.description};

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.retrieve_staff,
                cursor1,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
        listViewEdit.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity EditStaff and populate to ListView 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveType = data.getStringExtra("type");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveAmount = data.getStringExtra("amount");
                ReceiveImage = data.getParcelableExtra("photo");
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (obj != null) {
                        obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);
                        listViewEdit.setAdapter(obj);
                        obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
                    }
                }
```

**Edit_Staff**

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // return value to Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                Amount = amount.getText().toString();
                Description = description.getText().toString();
                claimType = type.getSelectedItem().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("type", claimType);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", Description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("amount", Amount);
                returnIntent.putExtra("photo", photo);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
```

**PicCustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class PicCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static ArrayList<ImageAndText> imgAndText;
    FrameLayout footerLayout;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ListView listview;


    public PicCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageAndText> img,ListView listview) {
        imgAndText = img;
        this.listview=listview;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void addNewItem1(String type,String amount, Bitmap imageFromClaims,String description)
    {
        ImageAndText image = new ImageAndText();
        image.setType(" Claims Type : " + type);
        image.setAmount(" Amount : " + amount);
        image.setImage(imageFromClaims);
        image.setDescription(" Description : " + description);
        imgAndText.add(image);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_image_and_text, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtType= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListType);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListDescription);
            holder.txtAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListAmount);
           holder.picture=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtType.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getType());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.txtAmount.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.picture.setImageBitmap(imgAndText.get(position).getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtType;
        TextView txtDescription;
        TextView txtAmount;
        ImageView picture;
    }
}
```

> So the issue now is when I click the save button in  Edit_Staff and
>   return to **Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**, a list supposes to be
>   added. But I still get the same list. What's wrong here ?

Comment: use 'notifyDataSetChanged()' after change list data.

Comment: @Srikanth not inside baseAdapter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating and setting new object of Custom Adapter to listview if object are not created but if it's already then not adding data to it's Adapter

first create Custom Adapter in onCreate() of Activity

```
obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);
listViewEdit.setAdapter(obj);
```

then change onActivityResult()

```
if (obj != null) {
    obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);
    listViewEdit.setAdapter(obj);
    obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
}
```

to

```
obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
```

or

```
if (obj != null) {
    obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);
    listViewEdit.setAdapter(obj);
    obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
} else {
    obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
}
```

Change adapter to

```
public class PicCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<ImageAndText> imgAndText;
FrameLayout footerLayout;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
ListView listview;
boolean mFirstTime = true;

public PicCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageAndText> img,ListView listview) {
    imgAndText = img;
    this.listview=listview;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void addNewItem1(String type,String amount, Bitmap imageFromClaims,String description)
{
    if(mFirstTime){
        imgAndText.clear();
        mFirstTime = false;
    }
    ImageAndText image = new ImageAndText();
    image.setType(" Claims Type : " + type);
    image.setAmount(" Amount : " + amount);
    image.setImage(imageFromClaims);
    image.setDescription(" Description : " + description);
    imgAndText.add(image);
    this. notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_image_and_text, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtType= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListType);
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListDescription);
        holder.txtAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListAmount);
       holder.picture=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtType.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getType());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.txtAmount.setText(imgAndText.get(position).getAmount());
    holder.picture.setImageBitmap(imgAndText.get(position).getImage());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtType;
    TextView txtDescription;
    TextView txtAmount;
    ImageView picture;
}
}
```

Comment: In onCreateView, I put  `listViewEdit = (ListView)edit_details. findViewById(R.id.listViewEditStaff);
        obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);`,  in onActivityResult, I change to `if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (obj != null) {
                        obj = new PicCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),images,listViewEdit);
                        listViewEdit.setAdapter(obj);
                        obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
                    }
                }`

Comment: when I click the save button, the first list will be overwrite by the latest list. I can add a new list now, but I don't want  the first  list(which was retrieved from SQLite) get overwritten.

Comment: you mean all records of listview added at initialization time should be removed after save.

Comment: No, all records shouldn't be removed. After save, it should create new list and add below the previous list

Comment: exactly you want remove all of sqllite and then after want to create new one and want to add new record into that with previous one..right

Comment: inside if (mClickedPosition == -1) { block add only obj.addNewItem1(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98353/discussion-between-tony-and-rohit-patil).

Answer (score 0):

You can add new item from listiview with adapterNotifyChanged.

```
images.add(NewAdapterItemObject);
```

and

```
obj.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

its done.